# Reading multiple values in multiple lines from file (Java)

Tags: java, file, input, line-by-line

Is there a way to read a file into Java line by line, with each line having a series of integers (different amount of integers per line). For example:

2 5

1 3 4 5

2 4 8

2 3 5 7 8

etc.

I will be reading the line number and numbers in each row into a 2-dimensional array.

Right now, here is the code I have:

```
int i=1, j;
try{
  Scanner sc=new Scanner(new File("mapinput.txt"));
  while(sc.hasNext()){
    String line=sc.nextLine();
    while(line!=null){
      j=sc.nextInt();
      Adj[i][j]=1;
    }
    i++;        
  }
} catch(Exception e){System.err.println(e);};
```

The problem with this code, I see, is that it's reading the integers one line after String line; I want it to read the numbers in that very line. Is there a way to read the numbers from a String?

Update:
I decided to go with the StringTokenizer route; however, when it gets to the last line of my file, I receive a java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found error. Here is my updated code:

```
try{
  Scanner sc=new Scanner(new File("mapinput.txt"));
  String line=sc.nextLine();
  st=new StringTokenizer(line, " ");
  do{
    while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
      j=Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
      Adj[i][j]=1;
    }
    line=sc.nextLine();
    st=new StringTokenizer(line, " ");
    i++;        
  }while(st.hasMoreTokens());
} catch(Exception e){System.err.println(e);};
```

Comment: Once you read in a line, split that line on the ' ' character.

Comment: The problem is calling sc.nextLine() advances scanner by a line (hence skipping a line)  and then you are calling sc.nextInt() which reads int next to that position.

Answer (score 0):

once you read a line you can do following

```
String[] ar=line.split(" ");
```

and play with String array based on your requirement

Answer (score 0):

Look into the #StringTokenizer class in Java Libraries.

You can easily iterate through the file and pull the `integers` delimited by spaces.  It handles the two + digit integers well.

To answer your question directly, there is a way to get numbers from a `String`.

Look into

```
Integer.parseInt(String s);
```

This returns an `integer` from the `String`.

Documentation is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html)

```
String s1 = "15 ";
String s2 = "03";
int answer = Integer.parseInt(s1.trim()) + Integer.parseInt(s2.trim());
System.out.println(answer);
```

This prints out:

```
18
```

Comment: `String s1 = "15 "` there is a white space at the end may be typo ( _never mind_ ) so can not be parsed...  :)

Comment: It was a typo. However you can deal with leading and trailing spaces with a .trim() call. Thanks